# How to extract a .wp-env.json or composer.json containing plugin versions from a production website?

Tags: plugins, themes

When having to migrate and/or start working on a client's website it's rare to have the original project on hand containing configuration files. Most of the times the website either was shipped with the custom theme and plugins already bundled and added or just built on the server using plugins from the store.

I'm having trouble replicating the same environment on my machine so I can start working with it. The problem isn't with the custom plugins or theme as there are only a few and probably aren't published anyway, the problem is with all the other plugins that are also installed and may or may not interact with the theme or other plugins.

Is there a concise, usual way of extracting theme and plugin versions into a config file such as .wp-env.json or composer.json without having direct access to the database?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a concise, usual way of extracting theme and plugin versions
> into a config file such as .wp-env.json or composer.json without
> having direct access to the database?

I assumed there existed a `.wp-env.json` generator, but I couldn't find it. That might help if available.

There are tons of ways to clone a site, but let's assume we only want to get a basic **auto-generated** `.wp-env.json` info directly from the main site.

Not sure if it's useful but here's a skeleton of a plugin that assumes only plugins and themes hosted on wordpress.org:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WPSE-407466 - REST endpoint for basic wp-env info
 * Version:     0.0.1
 */
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route(
        'wpse/v1',
        '/wp-env/',
        array(
           'methods'             => 'GET',
           'permission_callback' => function () {
                return current_user_can( 'manage_options' );
            },
           'callback'            => function( $request ) {
                $active_plugins = (array) get_option( 'active_plugins', array() );
                $data           = array();
                foreach( $active_plugins as $plugin ) {
                   $data['plugins'][] = 'WordPress/' . dirname( $plugin );
                }
                $data['themes']     = 'WordPress/' . get_stylesheet();
                $data['core']       = 'WordPress/WordPress#' . get_bloginfo( 'version' );
                // phpVersion only supports x.y not x.y.z
                $data['phpVersion'] =  sprintf( "%s.%s", PHP_MAJOR_VERSION, PHP_MINOR_VERSION ); 
                return $data;
            },
        )
    );
} );
```

A GET request (with a wp-rest nonce or application password) on:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wpse/v1/wp-env
```

as logged in user with `manage_options` capability will output something like:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "WordPress/buddypress",
        "WordPress/jetpack"
    ],
    "themes": [
        "WordPress/neve"
    ],
    "core": "WordPress/WordPress#5.9.3",
    "phpVersion": "7.4"
}
```

but note that this is not tested yet with wp-env, just used

https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-env/

as a guidance.

Here's an example using the [application password](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/):

```
curl --user "USERNAME:APPLICATION-PASSWORD" "https://HOSTNAME/wp-json/wpse/v1/wp-env"
```

where we replace `USERNAME`, `APPLICATION-PASSWORD` and `HOSTNAME`.

### Download link formulas

Let's add the versions for plugins and themes to generate download links.

If we only have wordpress.org hosted plugins and themes and if we assume they follow this download link formula:

```
https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/<PLUGIN-SLUG>.x.y.z.zip
https://downloads.wordpress.org/theme/<THEME-SLUG>.x.y.z.zip
```

Then we can update the plugin:

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: WPSE-407466 - REST endpoint for basic wp-env info
 * Version:     0.0.2
 */
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route(
        'wpse/v1',
        '/wp-env/',
        array(
           'methods'             => 'GET',
           'permission_callback' => function () {
                return current_user_can( 'manage_options' );
            },
           'callback'            => function( $request ) {
                if ( ! function_exists( 'get_plugins' ) ) {
                    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
                }
                $active_plugins    = (array) get_option( 'active_plugins', array() );
                $installed_plugins = get_plugins();
                $data              = array();
                foreach( $active_plugins as $plugin ) {
                   $data['plugins'][] = sprintf( 
                        'https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/%s.%s.zip',
                        dirname( $plugin ),
                        $installed_plugins[$plugin]['Version']
                    );
                }
                $data['themes'][] = sprintf( 
                    'https://downloads.wordpress.org/theme/%s.%s.zip',
                    get_stylesheet(),
                    wp_get_theme()->Version
                );
                $data['core']       = 'WordPress/WordPress#' . get_bloginfo( 'version' );
                // phpVersion only supports x.y not x.y.z
                $data['phpVersion'] =  sprintf( "%s.%s", PHP_MAJOR_VERSION, PHP_MINOR_VERSION ); 
                return $data;
           }
        )
    );
} );
```

with output like:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/buddypress.10.3.0.zip",
        "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.9.1.zip"
    ],
    "themes": [          
        "https://downloads.wordpress.org/theme/neve.2.9.2.zip"
    ],
    "core": "WordPress/WordPress#5.9.3",
    "phpVersion": "7.4"
}
```

### REST endpoint for plugins

There is also a way to extract info on the **active plugins** from the [plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress.org_API) REST endpoint.

Here's an example using the [application password](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/):

```
curl --user "USERNAME:APPLICATION-PASSWORD" "https://HOSTNAME/wp-json/wp/v2/plugins/?status=active"
```

where we replace `USERNAME`, `APPLICATION-PASSWORD` and `HOSTNAME`.

Example output:

```
[
   {
      "plugin": "jetpack/jetpack",
      "status": "active",
      "name": "Jetpack",
      "plugin_uri": "https://jetpack.com",
      "author": "Automattic",
      "author_uri": "https://jetpack.com",
      "description": {
        "raw": "Security, performance, and marketing tools made by WordPress experts. Jetpack keeps your site protected so you can focus on more important things.",
        "rendered": "Security, performance, and marketing tools made by WordPress experts. Jetpack keeps your site protected so you can focus on more important things. <cite>By <a href=\"https://jetpack.com\">Automattic</a>.</cite>"
      },
      "version": "10.9.1",
      "network_only": false,
      "requires_wp": "5.9",
      "requires_php": "5.6",
      "textdomain": "jetpack",
      "_links": {
        "self": [
          {
            "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/plugins/jetpack/jetpack"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    ... etc ...
]
```

This data could be used in a custom local script.

### Get download links from `api.wordpress.org`

If the formulas above are not always working, then we could otherwise get actual download links from [api.wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress.org_API) with a little more effort.

Here's more on this wordpress.org API:

https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress.org_API

The mock test in core had an informative link regarding [API parameters](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/206ee73bdd04ee515ff861f1d5cd8ac9b49ba1c0/tests/phpunit/tests/rest-api/rest-plugins-controller.php#L554).

Here's the info on the JetPack plugin as an example:

[https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.2/?action=plugin_information&request[slug]=jetpack](https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.2/?action=plugin_information&request%5Bslug%5D=jetpack)

that will contain zip download links within the plugin's version history:

```
    versions: {
        10.0: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.0.zip",
        10.1: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.1.zip",
        10.2: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.2.zip",
        10.2.1: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.2.1.zip",
        10.3: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.3.zip",
        10.4: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.4.zip",
        10.5: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.5.zip",
        10.5.1: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.5.1.zip",
        10.6: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.6.zip",
        10.7: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.7.zip",
        10.8: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.8.zip",
        10.9: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.9.zip",
        10.9.1: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.9.1.zip",
        11.0: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.11.0.zip",
        11.1: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.11.1.zip",
        11.1-a.1: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.11.1-a.1.zip",
        11.1-a.3: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.11.1-a.3.zip",
        11.1-a.5: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.11.1-a.5.zip",
        11.1-beta: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.11.1-beta.zip",
        11.1-beta2: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.11.1-beta2.zip",
        11.2-a.1: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.11.2-a.1.zip",
        ...cut...
        trunk: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.zip"
    },
```

It's possible to reduce the size of the response by turning off fields with `request[fields][<FIELD>]=0`.

As an example let's turn off the fields for contributors, sections, screenshots, tags, rating and banners:

[https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.2/?action=plugin_information&request[slug]=jetpack&request[fields][contributors]=0&request[fields][sections]=0&request[fields][screenshots]=0&request[fields][tags]=0&request[fields][ratings]=0&request[fields][banners]=0](https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.2/?action=plugin_information&request%5Bslug%5D=jetpack&request%5Bfields%5D%5Bcontributors%5D=0&request%5Bfields%5D%5Bsections%5D=0&request%5Bfields%5D%5Bscreenshots%5D=0&request%5Bfields%5D%5Btags%5D=0&request%5Bfields%5D%5Bratings%5D=0&request%5Bfields%5D%5Bbanners%5D=0)

with the output:

```
{
    name: "Jetpack &#8211; WP Security, Backup, Speed, &amp; Growth",
    slug: "jetpack",
    version: "11.1",
    author: "<a href="https://jetpack.com">Automattic</a>",
    author_profile: "https://profiles.wordpress.org/automattic/",
    requires: "5.9",
    tested: "6.0",
    requires_php: "5.6",
    rating: 78,
    num_ratings: 1778,
    support_threads: 248,
    support_threads_resolved: 218,
    active_installs: 5000000,
    last_updated: "2022-07-05 3:29pm GMT",
    added: "2011-01-20",
    homepage: "https://jetpack.com",
    download_link: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.11.1.zip",
    versions: {
        10.0: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.0.zip",
        10.1: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.1.zip",
        10.2: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.2.zip",
        10.2.1: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.2.1.zip",
        10.3: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.3.zip",
        10.4: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.4.zip",
        10.5: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.5.zip",
        10.5.1: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.5.1.zip",
        10.6: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.6.zip",
        10.7: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.7.zip",
        10.8: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.8.zip",
        10.9: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.9.zip",
        10.9.1: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.10.9.1.zip",
        11.0: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.11.0.zip",
        11.1: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.11.1.zip",
        11.1-a.1: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.11.1-a.1.zip",
        11.1-a.3: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.11.1-a.3.zip",
        11.1-a.5: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.11.1-a.5.zip",
        11.1-beta: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.11.1-beta.zip",
        11.1-beta2: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.11.1-beta2.zip",
        11.2-a.1: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.11.2-a.1.zip",
        ...cut...
        trunk: "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.zip"
    },
    donate_link: ""
}
```

Similar for the themes.

Hopefully this can help you to generate your own local config files.