# Getting current core version from an Wordpress installation

Tags: rest-api

I'm building an app for myself where I was going to check what version of Wordpress (and plugins) my customer has and see if it is in need of updating. But I cannot find an endpoint where I can get a response including the current installer version of a wordpress-site.

Does anyone have an idea for this?

Comment: how is your app interacting with the WordPress site? Do you mean an app as in a mobile app? Or a 3rd party webapp? Remote API?

Comment: @elmgren I recently posted an answer here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/407539/26350 that hopefully helps in some ways.

Comment: [WPScan](https://wpscan.com/wordpress-security-scanner)?